# Difference between GET and POST in an HTTP response (not request)

Tags: http, post, get, webserver

I already know the difference between POST and GET, but does the HTTP response changes when I make a request like:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.engadget.com
```

or

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.engadget.com
```

I'm doing a basic web server (Can't use php or any server-side language) for an assignment so I need to know if the response changes or is basically the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's up to the recipient of the request (server) to send back a response. The client can pass preferences to influence the response in the header (content type etc), but ultimately the response is determined by the server.

Comment: According to what you said, if there is no server-side language parsing the query strings, the response is basically the same, am I right?